# Which programming languages support constant methods?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

Which programming languages other than C++ support the concept of a constant class method?  That is, what languages allow the programmer to constrain a method in such a way that it is guaranteed not to change the state of an object to which the method is applied?

Please provide examples or references in your answer.

Comment: The vote to close this strikes me as misplaced -- it clearly is a real question for which a correct answer is possible (and there may be more than one correct answer). The "Please provide examples or references..." sounds like a homework assignment though.

Comment: This is a real question and not a homework assignment.  It originated from a discussion with a C++ programmer friend concerning an issue he encountered with constant methods.  During that discussion, I realized that neither Java nor Scala support this concept and that not many object-oriented languages that I know do.  So, I wondered, which languages do support this concept?

Comment: One of the best questions I've seen all of today. Why the close votes?

Comment: Where can I see the close votes?  Who gets to vote to close a question?

Comment: @Derek Mahar: I think you need lots of reputation (3000?) to see the close votes.

Comment: I guess I'll have to ask many more questions like this one before I can see the close votes!

Comment: @Derek: You need 250 points to be able to see the close votes and 3000 points to be able to close the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell, since it's [purely functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional).

Actually, every value/method is constant in Haskell even though mutable state/IO can be modelled through a mathematical construct called monad.

Comment: There is no one correct answer to my question, but I've decided to accept this answer as "correct" because it is true and has so far received the most votes.

Answer (score 3):

All purely functional languages are all `const` by default because purely functional languages have no state to be changed.

Comment: ...if by "allow", you mean "force" :)

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't use the word "allow".

Comment: You didn't use the word "allow", but I did in the original question which assumed that the default case is a "mutable" or "non-const" method.  This is true of most object-oriented programming languages, but, as you point out, not true of functional languages.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Fortran (95 or greater I think) has what you are looking for.  Coincidentally enough called "pure subroutines".

http://www.soks.org/view/Fortran95ForFortran77Programmers#pure_routines

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf91a.doc/xlflr/pure.htm

Comment: +1 you beat me to it by a minute or so.  Now let's sit and watch the discussion on whether or not Fortran is OO.  Should be fun.

Comment: "Pure" or "side-effect free" are two interesting ways to refer to `const` methods.

Comment: Though I had object-oriented languages in mind when I wrote the question, I avoided actually specifying object-oriented so that people would list many different classes of programming languages.

Comment: @Derek: `const`-method is not necessarily pure. For example, `void boo(int* x)const{*x=1;}` is obviously `const` but not pure.

Comment: A few years ago, I would have laughed at the concept of Fortran being OO.  And then I did a huge project with it.  

I was blown away at what I could do to write OO code without all the OO support in the language.  The biggest hangup I had was the lack of polymorphism.  But I remember hearing a while back that Fortan 2000, the language of the future :), will have support for it.

Comment: +1, but `this` would be modeled as an argument in Fortran and hence legal to change it within a pure method. - although using an index-as-`this` would match the concepts up nicely

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Methods), this feature is not available in many other object-oriented languages such as Java and C# or in Microsoft's C++/CLI.

Purely functional languages like [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), [Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_(programming_language)), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ωmega_interpreter">Ωmega do <strike>support</strike> *mandate* this feature.

Answer (score 2):

[ConstJava](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/constjava/) and [Javari](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/javari/) are two variations of Java that support the concept of a constant method.  ConstJava has been obsoleted by Javari, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this as C++, I think you mean `const` method like this:

```
class A {
   int e;
public:
   int doSomething() const { 
      // ++ e;    // Compiler error, change data-member in read-only structure
      return e+1; // OK.
   }
};
```

(Although C++'s const is not a true-const because of the `mutable` members.)

Then I'm only aware of C++, [D2](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/const-faq.html), and all those functional languages supporting this.

- [C# doesn't support `const` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx) but you can make all members `readonly`. You can also make a `readonly` wrapper class/subclass. Java doesn't have the const keyword, but like C# [you can make all members `final`](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/const.shtml).
- All functional languages use const correct methods by default because the functions are pure, but whether they support Object-oriented programming is another question.

Comment: Yes, I was referring in particular to C++ `const` methods.

Comment: Although casting away constness is undefined behavior if the object is actually const, e.g. a global-scope const variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write a custom attribute in .Net. The objects you pass in though, may all have to inherit from the same class i.e. EntityBase so you can manually ensure the state is the same.